# Policies towards "Find checkmate in x" type of posts

Tags: discussion, site-scope, protected-questions

I am curious as to where our policies stand for posts that plainly ask for "Find me checkmate in x".

To draw some analogy, e.g., on physics SE it's prohibited to simply paste exercises to be solved, specially if the OP has shown no effort/attempt in trying to solve it themselves.

- Do we allow for plain tactics (checkmate, etc) posts no matter what? [Here's a recent example](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/19687/white-to-play-and-checkmate-in-two-moves) of such a post.
- Or do we encourage the OP to explain where in their calculation they're stuck and try to rather encourage "How to solve" type of posts instead of "What is the solution here"? The latter entails no real discussions other than people posting one-liners with a variation, and consequently, the post will have no-longterm relevance specially because these posts will all have similar titles (they can easily be asked on chess SE chatroom). Whereas the former, will render the question into one about reasoning and methodology in approaching chess puzzles, with a concrete problem provided by the OP, and chess SE would be a far more natural home for those kinds of discussions.

I must say it is really surprising that these posts still keep appearing when basically nowadays on any website cloud-based engines are freely provided, the OP can set up the position in less than a minute (on lichess for example) and analyse it.

On another note, if we do allow for these posts, we need to consider actively ["protecting"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/06/07/new-protected-question-status/) the posts once they've been answered, because these are the kinds of posts that will draw a lot of views and in turn many new users posting 1-line answers either saying something wrong or repeating the same variation.

Comment: Personally, I don't mind seeing a mate-in-N or tactics problem now and then, especially if they're "good" ones. Somehow, these questions are likely to end up as Hot Network Questions, which inflates their scores. Protecting questions is only possible if they're [older than a day and have at least one answer by a new user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52764/295232).

Comment: If the outcome is ""we don't want them" consider writing one community Q&A along the lines of "Strategies to solve end game puzzles"

Comment: I don't think we should do anything as we don't have enough questions...